# Guice And Scala - Injection on Generics Dependencies

Tags: generics, scala, dependency-injection, guice, code-injection

I'm trying to create a binding of a generic trait using Guice

See how the `trait` is defined

```
trait Repository[T]
```

See the `trait` implementation

```
class DomainRepository extends Repository[Domain]
```

My configure method in `DomainPersistenceModule` is:

```
def configure() {
   bind(classOf[Repository[Domain]])
     .annotatedWith(classOf[DomainDependency])
     .to(classOf[DomainRepository])
     .in(Scopes.SINGLETON)
}
```

The variable whose dependence will be injected is:

```
  @Inject
  @DomainDependency
  var repository:Repository[Domain] = _
```

The injection occurs here:

```
val injector:Injector = Guice.createInjector(new PersistenceModule())

val persistenceService:PersistenceService =
        injector.getInstance(classOf[DomainPersistenceService])
```

The error is:

```
Caused by: com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for repository.Repository<domain.Domain> annotated with @module.annotation.DomainDependency() was bound.
  while locating repository.Repository<domain.Domain> annotated with @module.annotation.DomainDependency()
    for field at service.persistence.DomainPersistenceService.repository(DomainPersistenceService.scala:19)
  while locating service.persistence.DomainPersistenceService
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need a [TypeLiteral](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html) binding like this:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral[Repository[Domain]] {})
 .annotatedWith(classOf[DomainDependency])
 .to(classOf[DomainRepository])
 .in(Scopes.SINGLETON)
```

`TypeLiteral` is a special class that allows you to specify a full parameterized type. Basically, you can't instantiate a class with a generic type parameter.

Also, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45116111/1977778).

See "How to inject class with generic type?" in the [Guice FAQ](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-to-inject-class-with-generic-type).

Answer (score 15):

As David says, you need a `TypeLiteral` to bind a generic type (remember - generic types are erased to just the class, without the type parameter at run-time).

Another alternative is to something like my [Scala Guice](https://github.com/benlings/scala-guice) library to build the `TypeLiteral`s needed by Guice from Scala's `Manifest`s. If you mix in the `ScalaModule` trait, you would then be able to do something like:

```
bind[Repository[Domain]]
 .annotatedWith[DomainDependency]
 .to[DomainRepository]
 .in(Scopes.SINGLETON)
```