# How to override a TypeLiteral in Scala Guice when testing

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

In my `Module.scala` I'm binding a concrete implementation of a trait defined as follows:

```scala
trait AccessGroupRepository[F[_]] {}

@Singleton
class AccessGroupRepositoryImpl @Inject()(db: OldDataBase, c: IOContextShift)
    extends AccessGroupRepository[IO] {}
```

and the binding is done using `TypeLiteral`:

```scala
bind(new TypeLiteral[AccessGroupRepository[IO]] {}).to(classOf[AccessGroupRepositoryImpl])
```

Now, I need to override this binding when testing with a Mockito mock:

```scala
override val application: Application = guiceApplicationBuilder
    .overrides(bind(new TypeLiteral[AccessGroupRepository[IO]] {}).to(agRepoMock))
```

but I get the following error:

```
overloaded method value bind with alternatives:
[error]   [T](implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])play.api.inject.BindingKey[T] <and>
[error]   [T](clazz: Class[T])play.api.inject.BindingKey[T]
[error]  cannot be applied to (com.google.inject.TypeLiteral[api.v1.accessgroup.AccessGroupRepository[cats.effect.IO]])
[error]     .overrides(bind(repoTypeLiteral).to(agRepoMock))
[error]                ^
```

How could I solve that?

This question relates to [How to bind a class that extends a Trait with a monadic type parameter using Scala Guice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56668719/1977778)

Comment: Do you have a test module? Can you show it? Think that this question and the marked answer below can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483087/overriding-binding-in-guice/27803015

Comment: Unfortunately no, I haven't a test module, but essentially I need to find a way to do an `.overrides(bind(new TypeLiteral[REPO[IO]] {}).to(MOCK))`

Comment: I not familiar  with Play and scale, but you need to put the override in the test moudle and do the scale equivalent to
 Guice.createInjector(Modules.override(new ProductionModule()).with(new TestModule()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypeLiteral` isn't available yet in scala implementation of Play Guice API.

Current valid solution for generics, is creating a test module with desired mock definitions, and passing it within `overrides`:

```scala
object CustomMockComponentModule extends AbstractModule {
  val agRepoMock = ...

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  def mockBean(): AccessGroupRepository[IO] = agRepoMock
}

...

override val application: Application = guiceApplicationBuilder
    .overrides(CustomMockComponentModule)
    .build()
```