# Injecting F-bound polymorphic types by interface

Tags: scala, dependency-injection

I am attempting to develop a small component for a Play-based service and am struggling with how to go about the design. I need a service that provides access to "file storage" in various environments. My initial idea is simply to create a trait that represents the two primary operations (write/read) and then autowire the implementation based on configuration at runtime. The interface looks something like the following:

```
trait StorageService {
  def saveFile(name: String): Sink[ByteString, Future[Try[FileHandle]]]
  def readFile(handle: FileHandle): Source[ByteString]
}
```

The service allows a user to save a file to disk and returns a `FileHandle` object that contains all of the information the service needs to identify the specific file. The issue I'm having is that the `FileHandle` needs different information for each concrete implementation. Now, I can use F-bound polymorphism on the trait to solve this like so:

```
trait StorageService[A <: FileHandle] {
  def saveFile(name: String): Sink[ByteString, Future[Try[A]]]
  def readFile(handle: A): Source[ByteString]
}
```

However, the issue here becomes autowiring as I cannot wire the concrete implementations as `StorageService` providers without specifying the type parameter. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to accomplish this autowiring or perhaps a better design?

Comment: Have you considered moving the type parameter to the method level?

Comment: Title is misleading. F-bound**ed** would be something like `Foo[A <: Foo[A]]`.

Comment: Since Play relies on Guice by default, in Guice you can control the injection of generic instances using `TypeLiteral`s, but if this is your main problem, the title is even more misleading.

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271435/guice-and-scala-injection-on-generics-dependencies